# Vector bundles of schemes and their topological realizations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, schemes

Hi, there is a realization functor $R_\mathbb{R}$ from schemes of finite type over $\mathbb{R}$ to topological spaces and there is also a functor $R_\mathbb{C}$.

> Does $R_\mathbb{R}$ send an algebraic vector bundle $p:V\to X$ to a real topological vector bundle $R_\mathbb{R}(p)$ and does $R_\mathbb{C}$ send $p$ to a complex topological vector bundle $R_\mathbb{C}(p)$?

If this is actually the case I wonder if with $X=\mathbb{P^1}$ the line bundles $\mathcal{O}(m)$ over $X$ are mapped to the trivial bundle if $m$ is even and to the Moebius bundle if $m$ is odd.

Thank you!

Comment: Which topology are you putting on the topological realisations? Also note that even a trivial vector bundle, i.e. a product, may run into trouble because the functor from schemes to spaces that I'm thinking of doesn't commute with products.

Comment: It's presumably the Hausdorff topology, i.e. the one induced
by the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ for
subschemes. This would preserve products, and I think the answer to
the first question is yes. The second seems to  yes as well:
the $1$-cocycle for $O(m)$ in the standard covering is $x^m$... 